# use $1 as index of an array in replace function

Tags: javascript

```
var str = "1-2";
var arr = ["", "a", "b"];
```

**I would like to replace 1 with "a", and 2 with "b", here is my code. But it didn't work.Pls help me out.**

```
str = str.replace('(\d)-', arr["$1"]+"-");
str = str.replace('-(\d)', "-"+arr["$1"]);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use an anonymous function:

```
var arr = [ /* ... */ ];

str = str.replace(/\d/, function(match) {
   return arr[match];
});
```

Note, that this will only replace one occurence (commenters were faster that me editing; you might want to use the `g` modifier for the regex in order to repeat replacing until the regex doesn't match).

The anonymous function's arguments are the full matched string and capture groups (if any).

Comment: The regex should be `/\d/g` to replace both numbers.

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = "1-2";
var arr = ["", "a", "b"];
str = str.replace(/(\d)-/, function (mathchedText,$1,offset,str) {
    return arr[$1] + "-"
});

str = str.replace(/-(\d)/,function (mathchedText,$1,offset,str) {
    return "-" + arr[$1]
});

document.write(str);
```

Here's the working code:
http://jsfiddle.net/HsQC7/